# White box at the bottom of a view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

At the bottom of my page/view i got a [white box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4luU.jpg) that i can't remove. When i inspect elements there's no elements in that space (not even body or html)
I've tried to set body to height:100%, no paddings, margins etc but it made no difference.
Sorry if i've provided too little code, just shout if you need more.

Here's my CSS:

```
.header {
border: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px; 
padding-bottom: 10px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
h1 {
border: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 20px;
}
.container-fluid {
height: auto;
border: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
background-color: black;
}

.btn btn-primary {
border: 20px;
}
.card {
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.card-body {
display: block;
padding: 0px;
}
.card-title > img {
margin-rigth: 5px;
}

.table {
font-size: 20px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
 @{
 ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
 }

<div class="header">
    <h1>My Health Vision</h1>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add new goal</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card" style="width:400px">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"><img src="images/goal-icon.png" width="60" height="60" />My weigth goal</h4>
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Goal weigth</th>
                        <td>85</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Deadline</th>
                        <td>2018-05-30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Current weight </th>
                        <td>90 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Best weigth</th>
                        <td>87</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated with HTML.

Comment: Can you share with us the HTML?

Comment: It would help to see the HTML. Also, make sure to test without using addons on your browser (use a Guest session).

Comment: @Goediaz updated the post with HTML

Comment: I dont have any addons installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
height: 100%;
```

Use:

```
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: didnt do anything unfortunately

Comment: what ist the expected result? Black background? Becouse your body has no bg color :)

Comment: Nvm 100vh; fixed it! My     .cointainer-fluid    was set to heigth:auto and when i changed that to 100vh it filled the screen. Thanks!